# How to iterate over array of objects and update time if <mat-checkbox> is checked in angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6, angular-material-9

I have an array of objects that are within my `<mat-table>` the sync property is a `<mat-checkbox>`. I am trying to make it so that when a box is checked and then I press the "sync" button, it will update the lastSynced property with the current date and time within the table.

```
    export interface ConnectionData {
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
  connections: string;
  location: string;
  users: string;
  sync: boolean;
  lastSynced: Date | null;

} 

const CONNECTIONS: ConnectionData[] = [
  {name: '', active: false, connections: '', location: '', users: '', sync: false, lastSynced: },
  {name: '', active: false, connections: '', location: '', users: '', sync: false, lastSynced: },{name: '', active: false, connections: '', location: '', users: '', sync: false, lastSynced: },

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the method that's called on the sync buttons (click) that updates the table data. Something like:

```
for( const connection of connectionData ) {
    if(connection.sync) {
       connection.lastSynced = new Date(); // update to current date
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving an error. This is what my function looks like when I click the button, the bottom if statement is if I click "Yes sync" 
```openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      width: '350px',
      data: "Are you sure you want to sync data?"
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {       
        this.selection.clear();
      }
    });
  }
``` Edit: its not displaying neatly, sorry about that. Any ideas here though? I tried forEach earlier with no luck

Comment: If you are using a mat-dialog component, give it the `panelClass` attribute:
{ panelClass: 'my-class' } where .my-class { width: 350px; etc... }